# Easiest way to create measured intervals between shape points

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile

I need to import a scanned photo of the outcrop (geology project) and re-create the grid from which I took plug data- each plug point will be drawn as a shape point file.

The plugs were taken on a metre by metre grid layout. What would be the best way to ensure that the points are evenly spaced on the outcrop photos?- I guess I could mark the points on the scanned photo and then shapefile the marked points.

Comment: What software would you like to do this in?

Comment: I will be using ArcGIS 10. The idea is to create a kriging surface between the points using Arc Tool Box.

Answer (score 4):

if you can use arcpy this code could help you :

```
cur = arcpy.InsertCursor("ticks")

for i in range(int(extent_XMin) ,int( extent_XMax )  , int( interval) ):
    for j in range(int(extent_YMin) , int(extent_YMax) , int( interval) ):
        pt = arcpy.Point(i , j)
        row = cur.newRow()
        row.Shape = pt
        cur.insertRow(row)
```

this script creates a grid in "ticks"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to Python on the computer (university restricted access).

Comment: any way to do it with vb.net ? arcEngine

Comment: you can do it via geoprocessing in Arcobjects .NET

Answer (score 4):

To create a regularly spaced point grid, use [Create Fishnet (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002q000000).  In the attached image, I created a 50x50 fishnet grid.  However, you can specify any sized grid you would like--just make sure to check the "Create Label Points" box in the tool.

I should also point out that the regularly spaced point grid approach is appropriate for interpolation methods such as [local polynomial interpolation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003100000027000000) that assume samples were taken on a grid.  There are other interpolation methods that do not assume samples were taken on a point grid.  Methods such as [global polynomial interpolation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003000000006000000) and [empirical bayesian kriging](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0031000000q9000000) do not have such assumptions.  In case you are new to kriging, I would highly recommend going through through the [ArcGIS Geostatistical Analyst Tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Introduction_to_the_ArcGIS_Geostatistical_Analyst_Tutorial/0031000000nz000000/), which is very good.

[image]

Edit:

To add points along the feature vertices, use [Feature Vertices to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000) after you create the fishnet (see below example).

[image]

Comment: Ok awesome- the only thing is the data points- they are on each  corner, rather than in the centre. Would fishnet allow me to add to the corners?

Comment: @GISWiltshire I edited the post to address your comments.

Comment: Great thanks Aaron. I'll give this a go- effectively treating the scanned in photo (cross-sectional view) as a map. Probably pushing the bounds of the function, but do you know if the grid can be angled?- a number of the outcrops are dipping- only at very low angles (max 14). Thanks again. Chris.

Comment: Try orienting the fishnet by adding coordinates to the "Y-Axis Coordinate" input in the Fishnet tool.

Comment: Your welcome.  Good luck!